# How can I loop over this JSON result with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, loops

I'm trying to loop over the following JSON, but I can't figured out how to map the loop to the correct data item.

Alerting `data[0].ID` etc... keeps returning `undefined`, for example:

```
{
    "COLUMNS":
        ["ID","NAME","USECOUNT","EXCERPT"],
    "DATA":
        [
            [1443,"foo",20,null],
            [810,"bar",10,null],
            [690,"foobar",10,null]
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj = {
    "COLUMNS":
        ["ID","NAME","USECOUNT","EXCERPT"],
    "DATA":
        [
            [1443,"foo",20,null],
            [810,"bar",10,null],
            [690,"foobar",10,null]
        ]
}; 

// assuming you are interested only in the first elements of each DATA array
$.each(obj.DATA, function(i, val) {
    alert(val[0]); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AbVme/

Comment: That's done it. Thank you. Will accept as soon as it lets me.

Comment: Interesting. I'm running this in an ajax function, but it's craping out. Your JS Fiddle works. I'm using your code: `[ajax snip] 'success': function(obj) { //your loop goes here });` it gives me an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read propertly 'length' of undefined` -- it's not reading the data structs...

Answer (score 1):

```
jsonObject.data[0][0];
```

there is no ID

Answer (score 1):

The `COLUMNS` parameter and the `DATA` parameter are disjointed, they are two separate parameters.

If you want to do what you're talking about, you would need some way of determining which index "ID" resides at within the columns array.

```
var idIndex = getIndexOf("ID", jsonObject.COLUMNS);
var id = jsonObject.DATA[0][idIndex];
```

Comment: Mike, thank you. I understand. But Karim's solution seems to have taken care of it.